# PDF CMaps: Single Glyph to Multiple-Characters Mapping

Tags: ios, macos, pdf, adobe

According to this [article](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2012/05/understanding-the-pdf-file-format-embedded-cmap-tables/), the following CMap bfrange mapping is valid:

```
<02> <02> [<0066006C>]
```

Does that mean that PDF CMap parsers are supposed to recognize multiple-character hexadecimals and parse this as `02 = [0066, 006C]`?

I can't find anything corroborating this specific format in the PDF specification, unlike `startChar endChar [destChar, ...]` and `startChar endChar destChar` which are explicitly mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't find anything corroborating this specific format in the PDF specification

Have a look at the pdf specification ISO 32000-1 section 9.10.3 *ToUnicode CMaps* example 2:

> ```
> 2  beginbfrange 
> < 0000 >< 005E >< 0020 >
> < 005F >< 0061 >[ < 00660066 >  < 00660069 >  < 00660066006C > ]
> endbfrange
> ```
>
> ...
>
> < 00  00 > to  < 00  5E > are mapped  to  the Unicode  values  U+0020  to  U+007E  This  is followed  by the definition  of  a mapping where  each character code  represents more  than  one  Unicode  value:
>
> ```
> < 005F >  < 0061 >  [ < 00660066 >  < 00660069 >  < 00660066006C > ]
> ```
>
> In this case, the original  character codes are the glyph indices for  the  ligatures  ff, fi, and ffl.  The entry defines the  mapping from the  character codes < 00  5F >,  < 00  60 >,  and < 00  61 > to the  strings of  Unicode values with a Unicode scalar value for each  character  in  the  ligature: U+0066  U+0066 are the Unicode values for the character sequence f  f, U+0066 U+0069 for f  i,  and U+0066  U+0066  U+006c for f  f  l.

Comment: Thanks for answering! If you look at my question, you notice the format I'm referring to is slightly different. `<02> <02> [<0066006C>]`, specifically `0066006C` combines two unicode values, `U+0066` (f) and `U+006C` (l). I don't see that mentioned in the spec, all the example CMaps map single-unicode values.

Comment: @mattsven but that is exactly what the specification part I quoted is about! Here both `00660066` and `00660069` also combine two Unicode values each, and `00660066006C` even three of them! And this is described as *a mapping where each character code represents more than one Unicode value.*

Comment: My bad, I didn't read closely enough :) You are correct! Marking as answer.

Comment: @mattsven *grin* yeah, sometimes, having read a section again and again, one doesn't see anymore what actually is in it but instead only what one thinks is in it.